# Custom Sections Array for CoreData

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsarray

So I have this custom generated array for defining sections for my `UITableView`, but as you can see all the items are fetched through Core Data and sorted separately.

This my custom code:

```
-(NSArray *)tasks {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // retrive the objects with a given value for a certain property
    [request setPredicate:nil];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if ((result != nil) && ([result count]) && (error == nil)){
         return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:result];
    }
    return [NSMutableArray array];
}

-(NSMutableArray *)sectionsArray {
    // Fetch the scheduledDate check if it is in any of the term arrays and dump it in that section.
    NSArray *tasks = [self tasks]; 
    if (tasks) {
        NSArray *scheduledTasks = [tasks valueForKey:@"scheduledDate"];
        scheduledTasks = [[[NSSet setWithArray:scheduledTasks] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

        NSMutableArray *shortTermTasks = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *midTermTasks = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *longTermTasks = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSDate *scheduledDate in scheduledTasks) {
            NSString *dateString = [NSString dateStringFromFullDate:scheduledDate];

            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledDate == %@", scheduledDate];
            NSManagedObject *task = [[tasks filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] lastObject]; 

            if ([[self shortTermDateStrings] containsObject:dateString]) {
                [shortTermTasks addObject:task];
            }
            if ([[self midTermDateStrings] containsObject:dateString]) {
                [midTermTasks addObject:task];
            }
            if ([[self longTermDateStrings] containsObject:dateString]) {
                [longTermTasks addObject:task];
            }
        }
        sectionsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:shortTermTasks,midTermTasks,longTermTasks, nil];
        return sectionsArray;
    }
    return [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

I researched and found that `(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` defines how the sections are organised, now the question is how to generate my custom array here.

My `(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` looks like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**UPDATE: Code for generating `shortTerm`, `midTerm` and `longTerm` dates according to `[NSDate date]` in `sectionIdentifier`**
*Note: I made a lot of `NSDate` and `NSString` categories for this.*

```
-(NSArray *)shortTermDates {
    NSArray *fullDateList = [NSDate daysFrom:[NSDate date] to:[NSDate dateWithDaysFromNow:2]];
    NSMutableArray *daysList = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *dateString = nil;
    for (NSDate *date in fullDateList) {
        dateString = [NSString dateStringFromFullDate:date];
        [daysList addObject:dateString];
    }
    return fullDateList;
}

-(NSArray *)shortTermDateStrings {
    NSMutableArray *daysList = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *dateString = nil;
    for (NSDate *date in [self shortTermDates]) {
        dateString = [NSString dateStringFromFullDate:date];
        [daysList addObject:dateString];
    }
    return daysList;
}

-(NSArray *)midTermDates {
    NSDate *startDate = [[self shortTermDates] lastObject];
    int addition = 5;
    int dayFromLastTermDate = [NSDate extractDayFromDate:[[self shortTermDates] lastObject]];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithYear:[NSDate extractYearFromDate:startDate] month:[NSDate extractMonthFromDate:startDate] day:dayFromLastTermDate+addition hour:[NSDate extractHourFromDate:startDate] minute:[NSDate extractMinuteFromDate:startDate] second:[NSDate extractSecondFromDate:startDate]];
    NSArray *fullDateList = [NSDate daysFrom:startDate to:date];
    return fullDateList;
}

-(NSArray *)midTermDateStrings {
    NSMutableArray *daysList = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *dateString = nil;
    for (NSDate *date in [self midTermDates]) {
        dateString = [NSString dateStringFromFullDate:date];
        [daysList addObject:dateString];
    }
    return daysList;
}

-(NSArray *)longTermDates {
    NSDate *startDate = [[self midTermDates] lastObject];
    int addition = 8;
    int dayFromLastTermDate = [NSDate extractDayFromDate:[[self midTermDates] lastObject]];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithYear:[NSDate extractYearFromDate:startDate] month:[NSDate extractMonthFromDate:startDate] day:dayFromLastTermDate+addition hour:[NSDate extractHourFromDate:startDate] minute:[NSDate extractMinuteFromDate:startDate] second:[NSDate extractSecondFromDate:startDate]];
    NSArray *fullDateList = [NSDate daysFrom:startDate to:date];
    return fullDateList;
}

-(NSArray *)longTermDateStrings {
    NSMutableArray *daysList = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *dateString = nil;
    for (NSDate *date in [self longTermDates]) {
        dateString = [NSString dateStringFromFullDate:date];
        [daysList addObject:dateString];
    }
    return daysList;
}

- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier;
{
    NSDate *date = self.scheduledDate;
    if ([date compare:[[self shortTermDates] lastObject]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return @"0";
        if ([date compare:[[self midTermDates] lastObject]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            return @"1";
        } else {
            return @"2";
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping a table view into sections with a fetched results controller (FRC) requires two things:

- You have to set the `sectionNameKeyPath:` for the FRC. This can be any attribute (persistent or transient) of the entity, or even an arbitrary instance method of 
  the managed object subclass.
- The first sort descriptor of the FRC request has to sort the object into the same relative ordering as the `sectionNameKeyPath:` property/method. This sort descriptor can only use
  a persistent attribute of the entity.

You already have sorted the objects according to the `scheduledDate` attribute. To group the
objects into sections, you just have to add a "suitable" instance method to the managed
object subclass.

Let us assume that you have some date variables `shortTermLimit` and `midTermLimit`.
Then you could define the following method in a class category of your
managed object subclass:

```
@implementation Task (CategoryMethods)

- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier;
{
    NSDate *date = self.scheduledDate;
    if ([date compare:shortTermLimit] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return @"0";
    } else if ([date compare:midTermLimit] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return @"1";
    } else {
        return @"2";
    }
}

@end
```

Then you create the FRC using the argument

```
sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
```

Now all tasks that are scheduled before `shortTermLimit` are grouped into section "0",
the tasks that are scheduled before `midTermLimit` are grouped into section "1",
and the remaining tasks are grouped into section "2".

Note that the relative ordering ("0", "1", "2") is compatible with the sort descriptor
using `scheduledDate`.

But you don't want "0", "1", "2" as section headers, so what remains is to modify
the `titleForHeaderInSection` delegate method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSString *name = [sectionInfo name];
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        return @"Short Term";
    } else if ([name isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        return @"Mid Term";
    } else {
        return @"Long Term";
    }
}
```

Have also a look at the ["DateSectionTitles"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project from the Apple Developer Library, which works similarly to
group objects into sections by year and month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has helped me tremendously, but can you please help me with this error: `CoreData: FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptor without either disabling caching or using +deleteCacheWithName:` It was generated when creating a new entry.

Comment: Before I compared the dates according to a date string like so:`[[self shortTermDateStrings] containsObject:dateString]`.

Comment: @Ravin455: If the grouping into sections changes (e.g. because `shortTermLimit` or `midTermLimit` have changed) then you have to delete the section cache with `deleteCacheWithName`. Alternatively, you can create the FRC without cache, using `cacheName:nil`. If you don't have performance issues, I would recommend not to use a cache.

Comment: @Ravin455: My idea was that you don't need a list of dates or datestrings, but only the two "boundary dates" between short/mid/long-term tasks. If I understand it correctly, shortTermLimit is "today plus 2 days" and midTermLimit is "today plus 5 days", so you would just compute these 2 dates once.

Comment: Ok.. thats much better then. I will do that. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Please take into account that this will fault-in ALL objects matching your predicate (this has memory and performance implications on large datasets).

Comment: @MartinR The best and most thorough explanation on the net. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a transient attribute to your `Task` entity, call it something like `sectionName`. When the entity is saved or when `scheduledDate` is set, calculate the new `sectionName` and store it. Set `sectionName` as the key path to be used by the FRC.

Comment: So for clarification: Generate the `sectionName` during the entity's creation? But how about if the user edits the entity? Then should I generate the new sectionName again? Won't it be easier to sort the array every time the table view reloads?

Comment: Exactly, its easier to change only on edit (probably 1 or 2 items) than every time the table reloads.